# Type casting error Java, Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, type-mismatch, typecasting-operator

I am a beginner programmer in Java and this is the code that I have written so far:

```
public class Fastclass {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

    String[] data;
    data = excelRead();
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++){

        findcontact(data[i]);

    }
  }

  public static String[] excelRead() throws Exception{
    File excel = new File ("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Folder\\subfolder\\Data.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook (fis);
    HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

    int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
    String[] data = new String [rowNum];

    for (int i=1; i<rowNum; i++){

        HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
        String value = cellToString(cell);
        data[i] = value;        

    }

    **return data[i];**
  }


  public static String cellToString (HSSFCell cell) {
    int type;
    Object result;
    type = cell.getCellType();
    switch(type){
    case 0: // numeric value in excel
        result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        break;
    case 1: //String value in excel
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
    }

    return result.toString();
  }

}
```

Function excelRead is used to read an excel file and function cellToString is used to convert different data types cells in excel.

The findcontact function that is being called from the main class is the actual logic that I need to implement. However that is not important from the perspective of this question.

I get an error on the return statement in the excel read function and the error is cannot convert string to string[] (string array). Any help appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `excelRead` should return a `String[]` (because you're assigning the result to `data`, a `String[]`). That is

```
return data[i]; // <-- a String
```

should be

```
return data; // <-- a String[]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to read the code (probably formatting) but if the **return data[i];** is your return statement then you are just returning one element of the array which is a string.

just use "return data;" instead

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature:

```
public static String[] excelRead() throws Exception
```

says that you want to return an array of String, but you are returning an element (String) from your array.

Perhaps you want to return the whole array:

```
return data;
```

or change your method signature to:

```
public static String excelRead() throws Exception
```

and return the String array element like you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following method signature you should return string array

```
  public static String[] excelRead() throws Exception
```

where as you are returning a string

```
  **return data[i];**
```

either change your method signature so the return type is String or return the String []